# jQuery tablesorter how to find sortList object

Tags: jquery, sorting, tablesorter

I am using the jQuery tablesorter plugin.  I am wanting to store how a user has sorted the table on the page and automatically sort that way the next time the page loads.  To do this, I first need to be able to find the sortList object that stores how the table is sorted.  For the life of me I cannot figure out how to get it.  The documentation doesn't seem to have anything on this and I've tried everything I can think of.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to bind your table element to the tablesorter `sortEnd` event. All the data for that object is passed in to the handler. You can then get the current sort like so:

```
var currentSort;

$("#yourtableId").tablesorter({
    // initialization
}).bind("sortEnd", function(sorter) {
    currentSort = sorter.target.config.sortList;
});
```

Comment: Love it. Love everything about it. That is all :)

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bit less overhead to save the last sort only when you need it like this:

```
lastSortList=$("#mytable")[0].config.sortList;
```

Remember to declare the variable in the right scope of course.

(I think the questioneer's problem probably was that he had to get the DOM element via `[0]` and not the jQuery element.)

Answer (score -1):

this is how I managed to do it:

```
<?php
// Set session variables
$_SESSION["sortlistsessie"] = "[[0,0],[2,1]]";
?>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

//document.cookie="TestCookie3=[[0,0],[2,1]]";
$(document).ready(function() { 
// extend the default setting to always include the zebra widget. 
$.tablesorter.defaults.widgets = ['zebra']; 
// extend the default setting to always sort on the first column 
$.tablesorter.defaults.sortList = <?php print_r($_SESSION["sortlistsessie"]
);           ?>//      <?php $_SESSION["sortlistsessie"];?>; //<?php echo       
$_COOKIE["TestCookie3"]; ?>; 
// call the tablesorter plugin 
$("#searchTable").tablesorter(); 
}); 
</script>
```