# How to get cookie value from jquery tablesorter, which stores sorting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

In JavaScript code of web application, the table sorter is defined by:

```
$("#my-table").tablesorter({
    headers: { 
       1: { 
               sorter: false
           }
    },
    widgets: ["saveSort"] 
});
```

So when the page is refreshed the sorting of table is saved, but when browser is closed,  the table backs to its original sorting. So what I want is to get how table is sorted and save it to database. Can someone suggest me how I can obtain the cookie(s), which stores how table is sorted? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `saveSort` widget ([demo](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-savesort.html)) saves the information, it tests the browser for localStorage first, then if that isn't available, it falls back to saving the sort to a cookie. So, you can either use the function built into the widgets file like this:

```
var myTable = $('#table1')[0],
    myLastSort = $.tablesorter.storage( myTable, 'tablesorter-savesort');
```

or if you are using Chrome, go to that page and press F12. now click on the resources tab and look under "Local Storage"

[image: saveSort]

The value may look a bit confusing, but it's just a JSON format:

```
{
    "/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-savesort.html": {
        "0": {
            "sortList": [ [0,0],[2,1] ]
        },
        "1": {
            "sortList": [ [0,0] ]
        }
    }
}
```

And it is broken down as follows:

- "/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-savesort.html" is the url of the web page
- "0" or "1" would either be the table ID or the index of the table on the page
- "sortList" contains the actual sort list value

So as you can see in the above data, it is saving sort information for two tables on one web page.

Comment: Later versions of Chrome have the local storage in the "Application" tab.

Answer (score -1):

You could use jQuery to save a cookie with the sorted colum. The next time that page is loaded, use either jQuery or server-side logic to get the value of the cookie, and sort the appropriate column. This might be useful reading: [Can jQuery read/write cookies to a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95213/can-jquery-read-write-cookies-to-a-browser)