# Tablesorter plugin - what currently sorted by?

Tags: jquery, sorting, tablesorter

I am using the tablesorter plugin for a table.  Is there a way I can find out what a table is currently sorted by?  I am trying to append new rows to an existing table.  I have everything working correctly, but I want to maintain the sort.  All the examples (including the documentation which is barely existent let me just add) have an update being triggered and then setting the sort to something.  How can I determine what it is sorted by now, so when I set the sort, it is the same thing?

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you just look for the `headerSortDown` or `headerSortUp` classes applied to the header?

Answer (score 1):

Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955980/how-to-get-current-sort-order-from-tablesorter-plugin) help?

Edit: Also, [here's an article](http://ybits.net/2009/10/making-jquery-tablesorter-persistent/) that talks about using cookies to persist the sort across postbacks.