# Get column index and sort order while performing sorting using tablesorter?

Tags: tablesorter

Am using tablesorter to sort my table html table. Is it possible to get column index and sort order using tablesorter?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955980/how-to-get-current-sort-order-from-tablesorter-plugin

Answer (score 1):

Can you share some more details about when you need this information.

I wrote this answer assuming you want the sort information after a sort. In this example, only the first sorted column information is returned, but all sorted columns would be contained within the `table.config.sortList` variable ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/3470/)):

```
$(function () {
    $('table')
    .on('sortEnd', function(){
        var currentSort = this.config.sortList,
            firstColumn = currentSort[0][0],
            firstColumnDirection = currentSort[0][1] === 0 ? 'Ascending' : 'Descending';
        console.log('column = ' + firstColumn, ', direction = ' + firstColumnDirection);
    })
    .tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue'
    });
});
```